# Many to Many relationships in DJANGO with or without a relation table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, many-to-many

I'm new to Django. usually, when having a many to many relationships I would create a separate table to hold the relationship

can somebody explain how to do that in Django

here is my attempt:
a 'Etudiant' can 'Etudier' many 'Modules'
a 'Modules' can be 'Etudier' by many 'Etudiant'

```
class Etudiant(models.Model):
    id_etudiant = models.OneToOneField('Utilisateur', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_Utilisateur', primary_key=True)
    id_groupe = models.ForeignKey('Groupe', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_Groupe')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Etudiant'


class Module(models.Model):
    id_module = models.CharField(db_column='id_Module', primary_key=True, max_length=25)
    titre_module = models.CharField(db_column='titre_Module', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    uniteenseignement_module = models.CharField(db_column='uniteEnseignement_Module', max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
    finsaisie_module = models.IntegerField(db_column='FinSaisie_Module', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Module'


class Etudier(models.Model):
    id_etudiant = models.ForeignKey('Etudiant', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_etudiant')
    id_module = models.OneToOneField('Module', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='id_Module', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'etudier'
        unique_together = (('id_module', 'id_etudiant'),)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)?

Comment: @DanielRoseman is this way wrong? this is why i'm here i don't understand the manytomany fields thing in Django

Answer (score 0):

[From Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)

> For these situations, Django allows you to specify the model that will
>   be used to govern the many-to-many relationship. You can then put
>   extra fields on the intermediate model. The intermediate model is
>   associated with the ManyToManyField **using the through argument** to
>   point to the model that will act as an intermediary. For our musician
>   example, the code would look something like this:

```
 from django.db import models

 class Person(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


 class Group(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

 class Membership(models.Model):
     person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     date_joined = models.DateField()
     invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: does this mean that to add many to many fields i must add to module ... etudiants = models.ManyToManyField('Etudiant',through='Etudier')
...... and to Etudiant ......
modules = models.ManyToManyField('Module',through='Etudier')

Comment: @HammiCloud check the code. Relationship between Person and Group... only one of those has ManyToMany field which specifies the intermediate table being through='Membership'

Comment: can i just keep my code the way it is ... and not use many2many ? @aleksei-maide